# Parametric Equations (Basic) - Cartesian equation of curves

Tags: parametric

$x = 2 \cos t$, $y = 2 \sin t$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$

Find the Cartesian equation of the curves.

Please help i know it's basic but my problem is that $2 \cos t$ doesn't equal $1 - \sin^2 t$ and if it does how? (maybe i just need a re-freshener).

Help would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

Comment: Tell me which famous formula do you know that includes the basic functions $\sin t,\cos t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=2\cos t,y=2\sin t$$
$$\cos t=\dfrac x2,\sin t=\dfrac y2$$
since $$\cos^2t+\sin ^2t=1$$
so
$$\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2+\left(\dfrac y2\right)^2=1$$
$$x^2+y^2=4$$
this is equation of a [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) having centre ($0,0$)  and radius= $2$

Comment: thank you very much, you definitely reminded me since i was forgetting the fundamental theorem.